# C, function returning another function

Tags: c, properties

Why do some programming  languages forbid returning  subprocedures?  Yet the language C
does not?

Moreover How does C implement functions that  return  functions?

Comment: please define "some"!

Comment: Well there are many other languages that do not allow such a feature mainly the older languages such as Fortran algol etc..

Comment: you define "some" with the use of "many", that's cheating!

Comment: OK maybe you are right that I did define the some to many wrong, but that is not really related to the question. Some/few languages do not allow such functionality and I want to know why.

Comment: And you are sure this is not in reference to function pointers?

Comment: it is not in the concept of those languages (in those olde days it was not appropriate; or had too many unpredictable side affects; or the designer was more of a ruling type and wanted the programmer only so less control) other old languages like Lisp can return complete functions as results

Comment: I suppose it is related to the support of the function pointers but that would be the implementation C compilers have for the C functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think that you mean function pointers?
the reason that c can do that is be course c has pointers and you can declare them yourself and for example java has only a few hidden pointers

edit i found an example on the internet

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct container
{
  struct container (* call)(int);
};

struct container look_I_return_myself(int p)
{
  struct container result;

  printf("Here's some integer someone gave me, not sure what to do with it: %d.\n", p);

  result.call = look_I_return_myself;
  return result;
}

int main(void)
{
  look_I_return_myself(3).call(4).call(5);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Conceptually Java (and other OO languages) doesn't need to return function pointers, the OO approach means your objects are specialised for the different code you want to perform. Returning a function is too low level from the model.

Comment: i know that i OO languages you dont use it very ofthen i choos java as an example becourse i know it has no pointers (exept from some hidden 1)

Comment: @tinman, you obviously have no experience with closures if you think returning functions is low level.

Comment: @ikegami explain more please!

Comment: A closure is a language feature that ties data to a function (whereas objects tie functions to data). A Perl example: `my $var; visit($tree, sub { ... $var ... });` (`$var` could even go out of scope, and this would still work.)

Comment: Function pointers in C/C++ are not closures because they have no way to include ("close over") local data.  This is reflected in the fact that all C functions are "top-level":  syntactically, you cannot nest one C function inside the scope of another.  Languages with proper closures, where you *can* freely return locally declared functions with access to local data, typically need garbage collection to support this feature;  if you want to avoid confusing and annoying fans of functional programming, you might want to say "returning a function *pointer*" is low-level 8^)

Answer (score 2):

C functions **cannot** return other *functions*; they can only return pointers to other functions.  There is a difference.

One of the guiding philosophies behind the design of C is to keep it easy to *implement*.  That's a major reason why C compilers can be found on such a wide variety of platforms.  It's also a major reason why C provides so few abstractions.

Obviously, it's *possible* to design languages that treat function types like any other data type (Haskell, Lisp, Java, C#, etc.).  The designers of C chose not to do so because the problem they were trying to solve (implementing an operating system in a high-level language) didn't really call for that level of sophistication, especially considering the limitations of the resources they were working with at the time.  Remember that C is a product of the early 1970s.